# installing flutter in 2 users on the same device

Tags: flutter, dart, installation, flutter-doctor

I have [image]

sitory at 'C:/src/flutter'
'C:/src/flutter' is owned by:
'S-1-5-21-1322645445-554151150-51515950-1001'
but the current user is:
'S-1-5-21-3136349272-541265692-1777301837-3119'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

```
    git config --global --add safe.directory C:/src/flutter
```

Returning 1970-01-01 03:00:00.000 instead.

I want to make sure that has a solution and flutter doctor runs with 0 issues, and work perfectly in the 2 users without any problems

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool for easier Flutter Version Management. It will be helpful in your case.

FVM - https://fvm.app/

Comment: I can't ,its an organizations criteria to work with  this these tools